# "Is watermelon a fruit" - why is there no article before watermelon?

Tags: articles

> Is watermelon a fruit?

I tried to find a rule for that, and the closest one was saying that there should be no article when we talk about objects in general. That makes sense - this is a generic watermelon not some exact one. But we still say "a fruit" in the same sentence.

Comment: A perhaps commoner example is with colours: "Is puce a colour?" However, with _watermelon_, the indefinite article is possible. // I'd guess at massification.

Comment: When we say "Is watermelon a fruit?" (which I agree sounds odd) we asking whether watermelon is classifiable as a _type_ of fruit. Because we are speaking generally (in other words we are talking about whether we can classify all watermelons as examples of the type of fruit called watermelon), we don't use an article. However because we asking whether there is a specific type of fruit called watermelon the _type_ of fruit is specific, not generic. If we say "is watermelon fruit" we are asking whether watermelon is fruit in the way that all fruit are fruit.

Comment: But you can say, “Is the watermelon a fruit” where “the watermelon” refers not to a specific one but to the class as a whole.

Comment: @jim True but the usages are not mutually exclusive, they just have slightly different meanings.